# Autofill in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and kindly need your help.

I have code that uses an if statement and would love to be able to autofill. Here is the code below.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Sub PaymentPriority()
    If Cells(3, 4) = "FED_ASS_DM" And Cells(3, 5) = "NOCHG" Then
        Cells(3, 33) = "999"
    Else
        Cells(3, 33) = "No Value"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? To get going, turn on the macro recorder and do the autofill you wish, and then take a look at the resulting code and feather that in. Edit: Also, what do you mean by "Autofill"? It looks like you could just use `VLOOKUP()`, no?

Comment: What is problem with your code? It looks like good.

Comment: do you want to apply the same condition to all the rows starts from 3 ?

Comment: I am comparing two columns. Column A and B. 
If column A Cell 1 and Column B Cell 1 meet a certain condition, then display result in Column C Cell 1, 
else if Column A Cell 2 and Column B Cell 2 meet a certain condition, then display result in Column C Cell 2 .. so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The formula that you are looking for in cell AG3 is `=IF(AND(D3="FED_ASS_DM",E3="NOCHG"),999,"No Value")` which is what your VBA code is doing. Now all you have to do is find the last row and enter the formula in the entire range in 1 go.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub PaymentPriority()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sFormula As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    sFormula = "=IF(AND(D3=""FED_ASS_DM"",E3=""NOCHG""),999,""No Value"")"

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row
        lrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Enter the formula in the entire range in 1 go
        .Range("AG3:AG" & lrow).Formula = sFormula
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Siddharth... would this formula accommodate an else if. Say I wanted to more result output in addition to 999 and no value.

Comment: I am comparing two columns. Column A and B. 
If column A Cell 1 and Column B Cell 1 meet a certain condition, then display result in Column C Cell 1, 
else if Column A Cell 2 and Column B Cell 2 meet a certain condition, then display result in Column C Cell 2 .. so on and so forth.

Comment: Yes you can. The idea is to forst write the formula in Excel and then port it to VBA :)